# How can I disable "Press enter for maintenance( or type Control-D to continue):" message when enter the single mode?

Tags: bash

I log into my system with `single` argument to kernel, everything's fine. But one day after I `passwd -d root` and boot again, I found the shell asks me to press Enter or ctrl-d to enter my system. That's annoying for me, do I have any method to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happening in two cases:

- Bad mount options in `/etc/fstab`
- Errors on the drive your OS is on

Mitigation:

- Comment all the mounts in `/etc/fstab`
- Fix errors on the drive your OS is on by booting live linux and `fsck -y /dev/sda1` where `/dev/sda1`is the drive containing your OS.